# How can Magic: Duels crashes be minimized?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, magic-duels

In Magic: Duels, about half of started games crash.  When I am playing via Windows 10, Duels will quit, and a "Fatal Error--Unknown Error" or "Runtime Error" dialogue box will appear. What can be done?

Comment: Thanks for asking. When I am playing via Windows 10, Duels will quit, and a "Fatal Error" dialogue box will appear.

Comment: Thanks. It's usually mid-game. I haven't noticed that any particular action seems to be correlated.

Comment: Check for updates to your graphics drivers. Try re-installing (and/or if you are playing through Steam, "Verify integrity of game cache" under the 'local files' tab of the properties). Try reducing the graphics quality options. Try navigation to the install folder and manually running the EXE as admin. Unfortunately the error(s) the game is giving you are so generic it's nearly impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: The game crashes on a regular basis.  It's not your drivers, it's the game's shitty programming.